# Turning Converted Leads to Read-only on Lightning

Tags: lightning, leads, lead-conversion

Lead is already converted but still editable. Lead OWD-Public/Write/Transfer which i think doesn't have anything to do with converted leads. One solution is to create a validation rule to avoid fields from being edited if status is Converted, but its troublesome to maintain such big validation rule for each field. View and Edit Converted Leads in profile is unchecked. How can I make the Converted Leads read only or make sure that fields are not editable once its been converted?

Comment: You want to make total read only or want to allow some fields to be available for editing some are not which is controlled by profile

Comment: we wanted all fields. Is this a known issue/feature on Lightning? I kept on reading other articles saying that converted leads should be read-only and most questions are about opening it up for access, but for some reason, its still editable even if the profile i'm using doesn't have the the editing converted leads permission as per the spring 17 release functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your issue. updated the answer after getting confirmation

```
AND( 

    ISCHANGED(IsConverted ) = false, 

    IsConverted = true

)
```

Comment: Both those are unchecked on the profile that i'm using. That option is only checked on User Interface.  I tried them too i researched that before. Also for some reason IsConverted is not working. Its not firing on the validation rule so i still use IsPickVal(status, 'converted'). I don't know why but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple validation rule for this and check the value of converted field. Once lead is converted it will be true always.

```
IsConverted && PRIORVALUE(IsConverted )
```

Comment: I think he only want restriction on certain field not all

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty I think he want to complete restrict to it.

Comment: we wanted to restrict the entire record itself(all fields). So my current solution is use IsChanged(every field..etc). Also i'm not sure why IsConverted is not working. Still, thanks